# $f(x,y)=\frac{(y^2-x)^2}{y^4+x^2}$ continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

I'm having some trouble figuring the approach for displaying continuity of
$$f:\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$$
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(y^2-x)^2}{y^4+x^2}$$

I.e.

either display

$$\lim_{(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow (y_1,y_2)}f(x_1,x_2)=f(y_1,y_2)$$

or that for $y,x \in \mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ 
$$\|y-x\|<\delta$$ $$\implies\|f(y)-f(x)\|<\epsilon$$

Comment: HINT: write $$f(x,y) = 1 - 2\frac{xy^2}{y^4+x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it by definition. Do it by using theorems you know:

- The product of two continuous functions is continuous
- The composition of two continuous functions is continuous
- The sum and difference of two continous functions is continuous
- The functions $f(x,y)=x$ and $g(x,y) = y$ are continuous.

You only need to be a little careful about when $\frac fg$ is continuous ($g$ must be nonzero!)

Comment: You think it's "infeasible" to do by definition?

Comment: @mavavilj It's doable by definition. But why would you do that?

Comment: To see how it's done.

Comment: @mavavilj, I'd say that even continuity of $x\mapsto x^2$ is "infeasible" by definition.